# Cross-site cookie not set in split-stack Rails 7/React 18 app

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, cookies, cross-domain

I have a Rails 7 API and React 18 front end, both deployed to Heroku on separate subdomains. Locally, the Rails app runs on `localhost:3000` and the React app on `localhost:3001`. I need to set a CSRF cookie on the front end from the back end. I'm using the rack-cors gem on the Rails side to handle cross-origin requests. The CSRF cookie is set on the server side when the server gets a request from the front end to create an authenticated session. When the server verifies the authentication token (received by the front end from [Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference), it is supposed to set a `CSRF-TOKEN` cookie that will then be set in the browser and included by the front end in subsequent authenticated requests. I can see that the `Set-Cookie` header is being sent with the following value, but the cookie is not being set in Chrome in my dev environment (the site won't load in Firefox or Safari for other reasons, so I'm unable to test cookie settings in other browsers right now):

```
Set-Cookie: CSRF-TOKEN=c2Cn8OMs4IhgI5A4g1GC1XjG5hEc6RRW7dSPynxNbgsb0vsoWCr07yulWVzUwFYNP7dD8ARMps3pz5MMngKdog; path=/; secure; SameSite=None
```

My CORS initializer (`/config/initializers/cors.rb`) - `configatron.client_origin` is set to `http://localhost:3001` in dev environments or `https://sim.danascheider.com` in prod):

```rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins configatron.client_origin

    resource '*',
             headers:     :any,
             methods:     %i[get post put patch delete options head],
             credentials: true
  end
end

Rails.application.config.action_controller.forgery_protection_origin_check = false
```

The code that sets the cookie (this works based on inspecting the response in the dev tools):

```rb
cookies['CSRF-TOKEN'] = {
  value:     form_authenticity_token,
  domain:    :all,
  same_site: :none,
  secure:    true
}
```

And the code that makes the request from the front end:

```js
export const logInUser = token => {
  const uri = `${backendBaseUri}/sessions`
  const body = JSON.stringify({ token })

  return(
    fetch(uri, { method: 'POST', crossDomain: true, body, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })
      .then(resp => {
        if (resp.status === 401) throw new AuthorizationError()
        return resp
      })
  )
}
```

I've looked in various other sources and all say to do what I'm already doing.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie ended up being set when I added the `credentials: 'include'` option to my `fetch` request. I don't fully understand why this worked or was required on this request, but it did:

```js
export const logInUser = token => {
  const uri = `${backendBaseUri}/sessions`
  const body = JSON.stringify({ token })

  return(
    // Replace crossDomain: true (not a real option for 'fetch') with credentials: 'include'
    fetch(uri, { method: 'POST', credentials: 'include', body, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })
      .then(resp => {
        if (resp.status === 401) throw new AuthorizationError()
        return resp
      })
  )
}
```